# destroy_all non-existent subclasses

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a subclass that isn't needed anymore. Some instances may exist in each environment database. I would like to destroy them and all their dependents. It would be nice to be able to use `ProgramOne.destroy_all`, but obviously if I delete the class, it won't exist. Is there a way to use `Program.where(:type => 'ProgramOne')` without ProgramOne existing or is the best solution to start writing a SQL query?

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class ProgramOne < Program
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution was to create a rake task and set up the class there. That way the class was initialized even if the model file was removed and all instances and dependents were deleted.

```
# Rake task
desc 'Remove ProgramOne programs and dependents'
task :destroy_program_one_programs => :environment do
  class ProgramOne < Program
  end
  ProgramOne.destroy_all
end

# Migration
class PurgeProgramOne < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    Rake::Task['destroy_program_one_programs'].invoke
  end
end
```